# MDCDialog Uncaught Error: FocusTrap: Element must have at least one focusable child

Tags: vue.js, dialog, modal-dialog, material-design

I've a Vue single file component, and I'm trying to use Material Dialog within as follows:

```
<template>
    <div v-show="open" id="emergency-details-dialog" class="mdc-dialog"
         ref="mainContainer"
    >
        <div class="mdc-dialog__container">
            <div class="mdc-dialog__surface"
                 role="dialog"
                 aria-modal="true"
                 aria-labelledby="my-dialog-title"
                 aria-describaedby="my-dialog-content"
            >
                <div class="mdc-dialog__content" id="my-dialog-content">
                    Discard draft?
                </div>
                <div class="mdc-dialog__actions">
                    <button type="button" class="mdc-button mdc-dialog__button"
                            data-mdc-dialog-action="cancel">
                        <div class="mdc-button__ripple"></div>
                        <span class="mdc-button__label">Cancel</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="mdc-button mdc-dialog__button"
                            data-mdc-dialog-action="discard">
                        <div class="mdc-button__ripple"></div>
                        <span class="mdc-button__label">Discard</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdc-dialog__scrim"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import {MDCDialog} from '@material/dialog'

export default {
    name: 'EmergencyContactDialog',
    data() {
        return {
            dialog: null,
        }
    },
    computed: {
        open() {
            const module = 'clientDetails/editableDetails/person/ec/isDialogOpen'
            return this.$store.getters[module]
        },
    },
    watch: {
        open() {
            if (this.open) {
                this.dialog.open()
            } else {
                this.dialog.close()
            }
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        this.dialog = new MDCDialog(this.$refs.mainContainer)
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

However, when I `dispatch` action to set `isDialogOpen` to true, I get the following console error:

```
Uncaught Error: FocusTrap: Element must have at least one focusable child.
```

Also, `this.dialog.focusTrap_.elFocusedBeforeTrapFocus` is `null`. In the project we have another Material Dialog that works well, and it follows almost the same syntax of opening through dispatching vuex actions and calling `this.dialog.open()`, but that one has `this.dialog.focusTrap_.elFocusedBeforeTrapFocus` of `body` element. I don't know if that could be a reason for the error to happen, nor how to set `elFocusedBeforeTrapFocus`

MDCDialog's [README](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-dialog#handling-focus-trapping) has the following about `focusTrap()`

```
The MDCDialog component uses the focus-trap package to handle this. You can use util.createFocusTrapInstance() (see below) to easily create a focus trapping solution for your component code.
```

I'm just not quite sure how to properly create `focusTrap()` if that could solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your dialog (`.mdc-dialog`) is actually injected in the DOM, and that it contains at least one element `a`, `input`, `textarea`, `select`, or `button` with a tabindex attribute set.

For info, here is the function called by trapFocus (from `focus-trap.js`):

```
 var FOCUS_SENTINEL_CLASS = 'mdc-dom-focus-sentinel';
[...]
 FocusTrap.prototype.getFocusableElements = function (root) {
        var focusableEls = [].slice.call(root.querySelectorAll('[autofocus], [tabindex], a, input, textarea, select, button'));
        return focusableEls.filter(function (el) {
            var isDisabledOrHidden = el.getAttribute('aria-disabled') === 'true' ||
                el.getAttribute('disabled') != null ||
                el.getAttribute('hidden') != null ||
                el.getAttribute('aria-hidden') === 'true';
            var isTabbableAndVisible = el.tabIndex >= 0 &&
                el.getBoundingClientRect().width > 0 &&
                !el.classList.contains(FOCUS_SENTINEL_CLASS) && !isDisabledOrHidden;
            var isProgrammaticallyHidden = false;
            if (isTabbableAndVisible) {
                var style = getComputedStyle(el);
                isProgrammaticallyHidden =
                    style.display === 'none' || style.visibility === 'hidden';
            }
            return isTabbableAndVisible && !isProgrammaticallyHidden;
        });
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the [drawer's Web version](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer/web#types) and, as you mentioned, I just needed to add a `tabindex="0"` to a section element inside the modal's content, focusing the first `<p>` in that section (didn't need inputs/textarea).